# How to troubleshoot plugin conflicts on Joomla 3.6.5

Tags: debugging, joomla, breezingforms

I am having issues with the following components not working as expected. 
Crosstec BreezingForms
Crosstec ContentBuilder

For those of you who have used these extensions before, my issue is that the Content Builder List View will not display all submitted forms if "Create Article" in Content Template is not checked.  In summations, if an article is not created the form is not listed in the frontend CB List View. The List view should pull all form submission from a BreezingForm form regardless of how it was submitted (frontend, backend, breezingform menu item) but it is not.

I have been working with Crosstec Support and they cannot explain why they are not working as expected.  They say it may be caused by another extension.

I would like some assistance as to what I can do to locate the culprit extension.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try to do troubleshooting. Start by activating your error console in the administrative part, Second. Check for errors in your console. From my experience with the forms program. The errors will be from lack of program updates, extension conflicts, diferent versions of programs,or just programming errors.